# UV Grid not appearing

Tags: modeling, animation, blenderkit

[image]

Can anyone tell me why is the UV Grid not appearing on the model. I have applied it in the base color as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome, looks like you are in solid mode, switch to shader or render preview, you could use the shortcut (Z)

Comment: Not happening. It is projecting some weird design on the model. Not showing Checkered UV Grids

Comment: Show us the screenshot of that "weird design"

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16sdBqjwYiCqZfCNUcIgXsiGBaJaELbFs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like this "weird design" is simply your texture, but your UV unwrap is so small it reads only a small part of it.

Comment: Your screenshot says your using _Generated_ texture coordinates on the model. To make use of the unwrapped UVs, this has to be set to _UV_.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you please tell me steps?

Comment: @IshanBansal On the menu that is on the right (on you image), there is a dropdown menu with the word "GENERATED"

Comment: I couldn't find it. Please elaborate more.

Comment: @IshanBansal https://imgur.com/a/XKYyLdn

Comment: Got it! What is the next step?